# Agrupar dados com Sequelize e My SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Fala jovens, tudo joia com vocês? To precisando de um help que é o seguinte, quero fazer retorna os dados a grupados da seguinte forma

```
id_categoria1: [
    {
      id: 1,
      nome: "Arquivo tramitação 1",
      arquivo_url: "arquivo1.pdf",
      id_grupos: 1,
      id_categorias: 1,
      id_projetos: 2
    }
  ],
id_categoria2: [
    {
      id: 2,
      nome: "Arquivo tramitação 2",
      arquivo_url: "arquivo2.pdf",
      id_grupos: 2,
      id_categorias: 2,
      id_projetos: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      nome: "Arquivo tramitação 3",
      arquivo_url: "arquivo3.pdf",
      id_grupos: 2,
      id_categorias: 2,
      id_projetos: 2
    }
  ]
```

que agrupe os dados por duas colunas id_categorias e id_grupos, queria saber se é possível fazer esse retorno, atualmente tentei com **group** dá documentação do Sequelize porém ele não retorna os valores agrupados.

**Código atual**

```
db.arquivos_tramitacoes.findAll({
  where: { id_projetos: id },
  group: ['id_categorias', 'id_grupos'],
}).then(data => {
  res.send(data)
})
```

***Retorno Atual***

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "Arquivo tramitação 2",
        "arquivo_url": "arquivo2.pdf",
        "id_grupos": 1,
        "id_categorias": 1,
        "id_projetos": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "nome": "Arquivo tramitação 3",
        "arquivo_url": "arquivo3.pdf",
        "id_grupos": 1,
        "id_categorias": 2,
        "id_projetos": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "nome": "Arquivo tramitação 4",
        "arquivo_url": "arquivo4.pdf",
        "id_grupos": 2,
        "id_categorias": 2,
        "id_projetos": 2
    }
]
```

Acredito que fui claro na minha dúvida, desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### O comportamento do `group`

Você entendeu errado como o `group` funciona. Numa query `group: ['tipo']` ele irá agrupar os dados por `tipo`. Então se eu tenho:

```js
[{
    id: 1,
    nome: "A",
    tipo: 1
},
{
    id: 2,
    nome: "B",
    tipo: 2
},
{
    id: 3,
    nome: "C",
    tipo: 1
}]
```

Ele irá retornar:

```js
[{
    id: 1,
    nome: "A", // O id 3 foi "agrupado" aqui
    tipo: 1
},
{
    id: 2,
    nome: "B",
    tipo: 2
}]
```

Não faz sentido no seu caso.

### Alternativa

Você pode usar um `find` (do Sequelize) comum e trabalhar em cima do resultado da maneira desejada. Segue abaixo um exemplo com [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) adaptado de uma resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890276/8839059). Esse exemplo agrupa apenas por **uma** propriedade:

```js
const meuArray = [{
    id: 1,
    nome: "A",
    tipo: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nome: "B",
    tipo: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    nome: "C",
    tipo: 1
  }
];

const groupBy = function(array, propriedade) {
  return array.reduce(function(acumulador, objAtual) {
    // Pega o valor da propriedade. Por exemplo, 'tipo' do 'id'=1 é 1.
    const grupo = objAtual[propriedade];

    // Pega o array dessa propriedade "1" se existir, senão cria um array vazio
    acumulador[grupo] = acumulador[grupo] || [];;

    // Coloca o objeto atual nesse array encontrado/criado
    acumulador[grupo].push(objAtual);

    // Retorna o acumulador pro reduce, assim ele pode ser usado na próxima "iteração"
    return acumulador;

  }, {}); // {} é o valor inicial
};

const agrupados = groupBy(meuArray, 'tipo');
const pretty = JSON.stringify(agrupados, null, 2);
document.getElementById("json").textContent = pretty;
//console.log(agrupados)
```

```html
<pre id="json"></pre>
```

---

O exemplo abaixo eu desenvolvi para agrupar por mais de uma propriedade do objeto, mas pra isso você precisa escolher um identificador pro conjunto. Como você não esclareceu como seria, eu escolhi `propriedade1-propriedade2-...`. Provavelmente esse algoritmo não é a melhor solução, mas é uma opção.

```js
const meuArray = [{
    id: 1,
    nome: "A",
    tipo: 1,
    caracteristica: "Muito"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nome: "B",
    tipo: 2,
    caracteristica: "Muito"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    nome: "C",
    tipo: 1,
    caracteristica: "Pouco"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    nome: "D",
    tipo: 1,
    caracteristica: "Muito"
  }
];

const groupBy = function(array, propriedades) {
  return array.reduce((acumulador, objAtual) => {
    // Aqui vamos criar o grupo
    let grupo = "";
    propriedades.forEach(prop => {
      // Concatenando os valores com -
      grupo += objAtual[prop] + "-";
    });
    // E removemos o - do final
    grupo = grupo.substring(0, grupo.length - 1);

    // Aqui continua igual
    acumulador[grupo] = acumulador[grupo] || [];;
    acumulador[grupo].push(objAtual);
    return acumulador;

  }, {}); // {} é o valor inicial
};

const agrupados = groupBy(meuArray, ['tipo', 'caracteristica']);
const pretty = JSON.stringify(agrupados, null, 2);
document.getElementById("json").textContent = pretty;
//console.log(agrupados)
```

```html
<pre id="json"></pre>
```

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, acredito que esse solução seja a melhor para eu aplicar, testei aqui e deu tudo certo.